# Access scope variable inside script in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, timeline.js

I'm trying to create a simple application using AngularJS and TimelineJS3 but I'm having a problem with it.

I have a state (*timeline*) which contains a partial view (`timeline.html`) associated with a controller. This state contains a promise to fetch data from the server, which is going to be stored in the `$scope` variable inside the controller. The problem is that I need to access this variable inside a `<script>` tag in the partial view file.

Here's the code:

**app.js**

```
    app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 
      function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
      .state('timeline', {
        url: '/timelines/:id',
        views: {
          'partial-timeline': {
            templateUrl: 'partial/timeline.html',
            controller: 'TimelineController'
          }
        },
        resolve: {
          getOneTimeline: ['$stateParams','timelineServ', function($stateParams, timelineServ) {
            return timelineServ.getTimelineById($stateParams.id);
          }]
        }
      });
    }]);

    app.controller('TimelineController', ['$scope', 'timelineServ', 
      function($scope, timelineServ) {
      $scope.timelineData = timelineServ.indivTimeline;
    }]);
```

**timeline.html**

```
    {{timelineData}}
    <div id="timeline-embed" style="width: 100%; height: 600px"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.timeline = new TL.Timeline('timeline-embed', {{timelineData}});
    </script>
```

From the `{{timelineData}}` expression outside I can see that the variable has the correct data however, as I said, I'm not able to use it inside the `<script>` tags.

What is the best approach to solve this problem? I'm quite new to AngularJS.

Thank you in advance. Best Regards!

Comment: something like this needs to be intialized in a directive so that element exists when code is run

Comment: You can get a reference to the scope via `var scope = angular.element(elementInsideTheControllerScope).scope()` - then access your variable: `scope.timelineData`

Comment: using it like this `var scope = angular.element('div[ng-controller="TimelineController"]').scope()` and then accessing `scope.timelineData` I get that the data is undefined. Although, when logging the scope to the console, it contains a timelineData field with the correct data!

Comment: How can I use it in a directive? @charlietfl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work :)

On **app.js**, the code related to the definition of the state *timeline* remained the same. Additionally, I created a new directive:

```
app.directive('runTimelineScript', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
      window.timeline = new TL.Timeline('timeline-embed', timelineData);
    }
  };
});
```

And modified the controller to look like this:

```
app.controller('TimelineController', 
  ['$scope', 'timelineServ', function($scope, timelineServ) {
    window.timelineData = timelineServ.indivTimeline;
}]);
```

Then, in the html file for the partial view (**timeline.html**), I just inserted the new directive:

```
<div id="timeline-embed" style="width: 100%; height: 600px"></div>

<run-timeline-script></run-timeline-script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the controller OR the directive: after the promise is resolved, save the result on a global window variable and use that in your  tag.

```
app.controller('TimelineController', ['$scope', 'timelineServ', 
  function($scope, timelineServ) {
  window.timelineData = timelineServ.indivTimeline;
}]);

<script type="text/javascript">
  window.timeline = new TL.Timeline('timeline-embed', window.timelineData);
</script>
```

Remember that you need to initialze the TL.Timeline *after* the promise has been resolved in some way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but, as I apply it, I'm getting that the data is `undefined`!